# Between groups two way ANOVA - time points as an IV

Tags: anova, spss

I'm looking to carry out a between groups two way ANOVA and need some help.

The first IV is the group (two levels - control and intervention) and the second IV is behaviour across time (behaviour pre-intervention and post-intervention).

I'm a bit confused about how to do an ANOVA where one of the IVs is time points. This is because each of the two groups (control and intervention) recorded behaviour at both time points, so there are two sets of data for each participant for time point. And I don't understand how to input this in SPSS.

I know this is a basic question but any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: You have [tag:repeated-measures] data. You need to address both the between-subjects & the within-subjects aspects of your data in your analysis.

Comment: Thanks for your response. Would that then be a two-way mixed design ANOVA?